# Reactjs :Replace component with the button action corresponding

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

According to the buttons action's click  i want to change the components in the same place  also i  want to  use reactjs hooks

Comment: Okay, good luck! Here's a link to the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html - if you have any questions feel free to ask them!

Comment: Come on dude, show us the code you've attempted. And the specifics. What's the button's "action", how do you want to "change" it, what's the context of this use case?  Your title says "replace" the component, replace it with what? What are we replacing? How on earth are we supposed to help you with the level of detail you've provided.

Comment: okay i will explain : for exemple  first page is list of products when i click button update product i want to replace list of products with update products (one page) and i don't want to work with popup

Comment: @imen: what the other commentators mean, is that you need to update you question. Please add the code that causes the problem and explain what the code does or needs to do.